# How to display a loading icon when loading a form

Tags: vb.net, authentication

I have a program that needs credentials to be added to a log on form before the main form can be displayed. See code:

```
If loginSuccess = True Then
        'Me.UseWaitCursor = true
        If wincheck.Checked = True Then
            loggedinUser.currentUser = Environment.UserDomainName & "\" & Environment.UserName
        Else
            loggedinUser.currentUser = usernametxt.Text
        End If
        Mainfrm.Show()
        Me.Close()
        'Me.UseWaitCursor = false
    Else
        MsgBox("Login failed. Please check your credentials.")
    End If
```

The issue is, once the credentials are entered and the mainform begins to load in, there is no indication that the mainform is loading. I feel like a splash screen is unnecassery because it only takes around 5 seconds to load.

I either want the mouse icon to change to indicate something is loading, or I want a loading icon to be displayed over the login form.

Any ideas?

Comment: The usual signal is the WaitCursor (`Me.UseWaitCursor = true`). `False` when `Me` is done/closes.

Comment: Thanks Jimi, I'll have a look into that now

Comment: Unfrtunatley that solution doesnt work Jimi

Comment: I don't see what solution you adopted. Where did you set `Me.UseWaitCursor = true/false`? Update your question. This behaviour is the standard, you can find examples everywhere.

Comment: I've commented them in mate

Comment: You have to move everything inside `Mainfrm`. You can set `UseWaitCursor = true` in its designer. Then, set it to `false` in the `Shown` event (for example).

Comment: That worked mate, cheers. copy and paste that as an answer if you like and I'll mark it as answered.